# Is what constitutes outrageous conduct clearly defined in the statutes?

Tags: police, human-rights, us-constitution, entrapment

Are there any objective rules or guidelines used to determine whether a police officer's conduct was outrageous?

Comment: Which statutes?

Comment: Why would anyone care - outrageous conduct is not a crime

Comment: @DaleM maybe not but it's a mitigating factor.

Comment: I don't know the answer but if it's not spelled out in a statute and a judge hasn't taken care of it your next stop is statutory interpretation. I don't have time right now but here's a start: https://www.law.georgetown.edu/academics/academic-programs/legal-writing-scholarship/writing-center/upload/statutoryinterpretation.pdf

Answer (score 1):

"outrageous conduct" has sometimes been a factor in holding police action invalid under the uS Federal constitution. In particular, there was a line of Supreme Court decisions that would supress confessions if they were obtained by "outrageous conduct". That line of cases became obselete with the *Miranda* ruling requiring warnings, and also forbidding most of the sorts of things previously lumped under "outrageous conduct". This sense of "outrageous conduct" was a purely court-made concept, not a statutory one, and the standard seemd to have been conduct that was considered shocking or unconscionable by at least 5 Justices.